# Observe lifecycle of jetpack compose navigator to get current screen name

Tags: android, navigation, android-jetpack-compose, jetpack-compose-navigation

Because fragments are not used in Jetpack navigation, I want to observe the lifecycle of jetpack navigator to get current destination or screen name. As you know Jetpack navigation is not using fragments rather it uses deep linking structure. I searched a lot but couldn't find any suitable solution.

I want to get the route or destination name for my sdk to track the screens flow.

```
    class AppLifeCycleObserver : Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks {

    var route: String? = ""

    override fun onActivityCreated(p0: Activity, p1: Bundle?) {
        log("onActivityCreated")
    }

    val TAG = "AppLifeCycleObserver"

    fun log(message: String) {
        Log.e(TAG, message)
    }

    override fun onActivityStarted(p0: Activity) {
        log("onActivityStarted")

        if (p0 is FragmentActivity) {
            p0.supportFragmentManager.registerFragmentLifecycleCallbacks(object :
                FragmentManager.FragmentLifecycleCallbacks() {

                override fun onFragmentCreated(
                    fm: FragmentManager,
                    f: Fragment,
                    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
                ) {
                    super.onFragmentCreated(fm, f, savedInstanceState)
                    log("onFragmentCreated")
                }


                override fun onFragmentDestroyed(fm: FragmentManager, f: Fragment) {
                    super.onFragmentDestroyed(fm, f)
                    log("onFragmentDestroyed")
                }

            }, true)
        } else if (p0 is ComponentActivity) {
          (p0 as MasterActivity).navController_field.currentBackStackEntry.destination.route
            log("ComponentActivity")
        }

    }

    override fun onActivityResumed(p0: Activity) {
        log("onActivityResumed")
    }

    override fun onActivityPaused(p0: Activity) {
        log("onActivityPaused")
    }

    override fun onActivityStopped(p0: Activity) {
        log("onActivityStopped")
    }

    override fun onActivitySaveInstanceState(p0: Activity, p1: Bundle) {

    }

    override fun onActivityDestroyed(p0: Activity) {
        log("onActivityDestroyed")
    }



}
```

I can't access the

```
      (p0 as MasterActivity).navController_field.currentBackStackEntry.destination.route
```

because this is inaccessible , I find it through debugging

Answer (score 2):

`navController` initialization doesn't have to be a public field of an activity.
In the google [docs](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/navigation) users are required to call `rememberNavController()` inside activity setContent() and that's it.

So perhaps you can ask the users of your SDK to provide the navHostController as an initialization argument, or is this not an option?

Comment: Yes thats the work around I have already implemented. I am taking the navController instance from user and then set addOnDistinationListener on it.
If there is no other way than this is the only solution.

Comment: Yes I think this is a good solution until they add a method `getNavController()` or something like that